# Strange Import Behaviour

Tags: vb.net, import, scope

i've 2 class in the same folder.

```
Public NotInheritable Class GestioneConstants

    Public Shared NAME_CONST As String                = "try"

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class GestioneConstants2

    Public Shared NAME_CONST As String                = "try"

End Class
```

as you see just the name is different.

Now if i'm in another class and i try to do: "Imports." i can't see the second class.

Why?

EDIT: i'm adding some photos

The files in my app_code folder (all NotInhritable Class)

[image: the files in my app_code folder]

What happens if i try to write "GestionConstants" in a WebService

[image]

and what happens if i try to write "URLFactory" in the same WebService -> NOTHING

[image]

And if i try to write the namespace of my app i don't see all my files:

[image]

As u can see i don't see GestioneCommesseQueryBuilder.vb for example

Comment: I doubt that this is the actual code since it wouldn't compile anyway. `TRY` is a [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409611.aspx) which you must not use.

Comment: well -.- the code is the same, but not with "TRY" as name

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong. I've tested it and it works for me. However, you have a naming issue if you want to import both and both have `NAME_CONST` (_"The name 'NAME_CONST' is ambiguous. 'NAME_CONST' is defined in both the 'Y' namespace and the 'Z' namespace."_).

Comment: Yes i know.. but actually i can't use the second class from other resources :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Don't know why the classes for i had the problems had the properties "Build Action" set to "Content".

I've changed to "Compile" and now all working